# How to download file into unity from remote server

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have an empty gameobject with a script component added in my scene. What I want to do is when a user collides with this gameobject a img file is downloaded from a remote server and displayed...

I know a little about the WWW unity class but I am not 100% how to implement it to do what I want, any code suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
IEnumerator LoadPictureAnimate (string url) {
    WWW www = new WWW(url);
    yield return www;

    Texture2D texture2D = www.texture;

    Rect textureRect = new Rect(0, 0, texture2D.width, texture2D.height);
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite.Create (texture2D, textureRect, new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
}
```